# Name Servers not resolving

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, bind, centos6

I just got myself an unmanaged Dedicated VPS from OVH and I don't have a prior experience of setting up servers or DNS servers but I followed a couple of tuts and installed webmin and created NS Zones for my Domain but now I'm having a weird issue where mxtoolbox and intodns.com are saying that no NS records are found for my Domain although I did register  ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com with my domain registrar (which is Network Solutions in this case) but it still keeps failing and I am unable to access the website. I have been looking for a solution for 2 days now and I still haven't gotten one. Also, I am using CentOs 6.3. Here is my BIND config which I got from Webmin

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//
options {
listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 198.245.51.xxx;};
listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
directory   "/var/named";
dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
allow-query     { localhost; any; };                      ## IP Range ##
allow-transfer  { localhost; 198.245.51.xxx; };                        ## Slave     DNS IP ## 
recursion yes;
dnssec-enable yes;
dnssec-validation yes;
dnssec-lookaside auto;
/* Path to ISC DLV key */
bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
forwarders {
    198.245.51.xxx;
    8.33.137.xxx;
    };
};
logging {
    channel default_debug {
            file "data/named.run";
            severity dynamic;
    };
};
zone "." IN {
type hint;
file "named.ca";
};
include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
zone "example.org" {
type master;
file "/var/named/example.org.hosts";
allow-transfer {
    8.33.137.xxx;
    };
also-notify {
    8.33.137.xxx;
    };
};
zone "221.51.245.198.in-addr.arpa" {
type master;
file "/var/named/198.245.51.xxx.rev";
};
```

**My IP table rules**:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjhCj.png

**My hosts file:-**

```
Do not remove the following line, or various programs
that require network functionality will fail.

127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost

198.245.51.xxx  ns1

198.245.51.xxx  example.org

198.245.51.xxx  ns1.example.org

198.245.51.xxx  ns1.example.org.
```

**My resolv.conf file**:-

```
namserver 198.245.51.xxx
ns1.example.org 198.245.51.xxx
ns2.example.org 8.33.137.xxx
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 213.186.33.xx
search ovh.net
```

**intodns.com results**:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oghxr.png

**Note:- Just in case there is any confusion regarding the domain** *example.org*, I just use this alias to mask my domain name but I'm pretty sure you guys already figured that out so just putting it out there.

Thank you very much for your reply!

**UPDATE:-**

**My Zone File:-**

```
$ttl 38400
example.org.    IN  SOA ns1.example.org. admin.example.org. (
        1368243151
        10800
        3600
        604800
        38400 )
example.org.    IN  NS  ns1.example.org.
example.org.    IN  A   198.245.51.xxx
www.example.org.    IN  A   198.245.51.xxx
ns1.example.org.    30m IN  A   198.245.51.xxx
example.org.    IN  NS  ns2.example.org.
ns2.example.org.    IN  A   8.33.137.xxx
198.245.51.xxx.example.org. IN  PTR ns1
198.245.51.xxx.example.org. IN  PTR example.org
```

**My Zone overview**:-
        *Zone*
    ***Zone***: Root zone           ***Type***: Root
    ***Zone***: 0                  ***Type***: Master
    ***Zone***: 0000::1         ***Type***: Master
    ***Zone***: 127.0.0.1           ***Type***: Master 
    ***Zone***: 198.245.51.xxx  ***Type***: Master
    ***Zone***: localhost   Master
    ***Zone***: localhost.localdomain   ***Type***: Master
    ***Zone***: example.org     ***Type***:Master;

**My dig results**:-

```
[xxxx@xxxxxx ~]# dig ns1.example.org

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.4 <<>> ns1.example.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19537
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns1.example.org.            IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ns1.example.org.     1800    IN      A       198.245.51.xxx

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.org.         38400   IN      NS      ns1.example.org.
example.org.         38400   IN      NS      ns2.example.org.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns2.example.org.     38400   IN      A       8.33.137.xxx

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sat May 11 23:01:48 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 100
```

Please let me know if you need anymore info.

Comment: Where is your zone file?

Comment: @MichaelHampton added. please let me know if I can provide you with anything else.

Comment: That doesn't look particularly wrong. If you really want this solved in any reasonable amount of time, you should probably disclose the domain name.

Comment: Seriously. Obfuscating your domain name and your ip addresses doesn't make anything any more secure. You came here for help so how about helping us to help you by giving us the real domain name at the very least. If you're worried about disclosing your domain name then why register it in the first place? The information you've obfuscated is already available to some parties and will be available to everyone once the problem is solved, so I don't see the point in your not disclosing it in your question.

Comment: Right now it looks like Network Solutions is authoritative for your domain. The NS records returned for your domain name are ns19.worldnic.com and ns20.worldnic.com. That's assuming that your domain name is powerbuddy.com.

Comment: Can you watch the network traffic with `wireshark` or `tcpdump` to see if there's something going out at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a firewall running, and as i remember CentOS's default firewall block port 53 (though i may be wrong here).

---

Change

```
allow-query     { localhost; any; };
```

with

```
allow-query     { any; };
```

maybe that causing some problem.
Also delete the :

```
forwarders {
198.245.51.xxx;
8.33.137.xxx;
};
```

since i believe that 2 IP is your own IP.

Restart bind, and after restart check that is really running with `ps -ef | grep bind` .

Comment: I think I took care of it, would you mind have a look please? http://i.imgur.com/uIwOWIK.png

These are my firewall rules.

Comment: Looks ok, still doesn't work?

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So when you setup your DNS name server records, there are two components:

1) Glue Record - This is what happens when you register your name servers with the registrar.

2) NS Records - You need to create a dns zone for example.org or whatever your domain is, and create A records for ns1 and ns2, pointing to the IPs that you set in your Glue records.

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://i.imgur.com/PXUFHLe.png

If so, then I already have it setup.